# Changing variables in competition model

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

reading wikipedia articule I found that they are few equivalent ways to define competetive Lotka-Volterra equations. 
$$\frac{dx_i}{dt}=r_ix_i(1-\frac{\sum_{j=1}^{n}a_{ij}x_j}{K_i})$$
And:
$$\frac{dx_i}{dt}=r_ix_i(1-\sum_{j=1}^{n}a_{ij}x_j)$$
 I wanted to find a substituion to get from first the second. Obvious one $y_j=\frac{x_j}{K_i}$ doesn't seem to get the job done. I will be very glad for a help.

Comment: As noted in the article you mentioned ([read this carefully](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Competitive_Lotka%E2%80%93Volterra_equations#N_species)), this is not a change of the variable, but a reparametrisation of the $A$ matrix (basically, $a_{ij} \mapsto a_{ij}/K_i$), which represents a change in how the interaction is defined.

Comment: Of course you are right I read it couple of times but I apparently missed it.

Answer (score 0):

The row of the interaction matrix for species i is

$\begin{pmatrix} a_{i1}&a_{i2}&a_{i3}&\ldots &a_{iN}& \end{pmatrix}$

Together with the amount of the N populations and the capacity $K_i$ it becomes

$$\frac1{K_i}\cdot \begin{pmatrix} a_{i1}&a_{i2}&a_{i3}&\ldots &a_{iN}& \end{pmatrix}\cdot \begin{pmatrix} x_{1} \\ x_{2} \\x_{3} \\ \vdots \\ x_{N} \\ \end{pmatrix}=\frac{\sum_{j=1}^{N}a_{ij}x_j}{K_i}$$

$\frac1{K_i}$ is a scalar. Thus  every element of $a_{ij}$ can be multiplied by $\frac1{K_i}$. That is what is meant at Wiki by "*pulling into the interacive matrix*"

$$\begin{pmatrix} \frac{a_{i1}}{K_i}&\frac{a_{i2}}{K_i}&\frac{a_{i3}}{K_i}&\ldots &\frac{a_{iN}}{K{i}}\end{pmatrix}\cdot \begin{pmatrix} x_{1} \\ x_{2} \\x_{3} \\ \vdots \\ x_{N} \\ \end{pmatrix}=\sum_{j=1}^{N}\frac{a_{ij}}{K_i}x_j$$

Equivalently the factor can be put into the sum since it does not depend on index $j$.

Now you can use your substitution $y_{ij}=\frac{a_{ij}}{K_i}$ to get a simplified expression